# Slow disk write performance on nvme SSD with Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)

Tags: drivers, ssd, performance, 18.10

On Gigabyte 15W V8(CPU i7-8750H, Mobile HM370) the write performance on EVO 970 Pro is disappointing.

The write performance is only 600 MBi compared to 2550 MBi with Win10.

[Disk performance Ubuntu 18.10, 4.18.0-11-generic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIKzA.png)

When testing with Mint 18.02, 4.8.53, the performance is comparable to the measured Win10 values.

[Disk performance Mint 18.02, 4.8.53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNpER.png)

Comparing the lspci values gives a difference for the PCI bridge:

*4.8.53:    00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)

4.18.0-11: 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)*

How could i direct the kernel to use the Sky Lake PCIe Controller driver?

Comment: Have You tried installing one of the latest kernels and test again ?