# NVMe SSD slow write speed

Tags: kernel, ssd, performance, nvme, pcie

I have a NUC (BEH model) and a M.2 SSD PCIe gen3 NMVe card (Samsung 970 pro 512GB) and I have a slow and fast write speed result in Ubuntu 18.04.3 with two different kernels. I used [ukuu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu) for kernel switching and in kernel 5.0+ which comes standard with the Ubuntu installer I get around 600MiB ( sad ) write speed and with a previous kernel version of 4.9.190, I get around 2200MiB with the benchmark tool in Ubuntu. I have tried the latest 5.2 kernel and it is still a problem. I have tried Linux mint 19.2 and I also get the a slow write speed because it is using a later kernel than 4.9.

Here is my [benchmark result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2GGK.jpg) on kernel 4.9.190.

I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005396/ssd-slow-write-speed-on-ubuntu) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097125/slow-disk-write-performance-on-nvme-ssd-with-ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish?rq=1&newreg=c24a49baba0845a497b05716a27536ee) are related problems and a simple google search indicates lots of SSD write performance issues. Could it be a massive potential linux kernel performance issue?

Any help or fix would be greatly welcome!

Comment: Same issue here, did you fix it?

Comment: Hi Maxime, please find my work-around below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the kernel itself might be ok but somewhere in the benchmark tool (Disks) of ubuntu could be the issue.

Solution (work-around): I created a directory in the disk to be tested and then terminal into the directory and ran two commands on it. The first commands creates a temp file (4GB in size) and tests the write speed of the disk and the second command reads that file and tests the read speed.

The commands: -write: `dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=4096 conv=fdatasync,notrunc status=progress oflag=direct` -read: `dd if=tempfile of=/dev/null bs=1M count=4096 status=progress iflag=direct`

Here is my result: [image: terminal command results]

Answer (score 2):

The problem described is about the same here.
I have a computer with ASUS Z10PE motherboard. That one has an in-built M2 NVMe slot.
I also added 1 PCIe card that supports 1 NVMe drive.
I also modded the BIOS to get bifurcation mode to have one PCIe slot to be divided in 4X4X4X4 so I can fit in the ASUS M2 Hyper PCIe card that allows up to 4 NVMe drives.

If I use GNOME-DISKS tool, that allows to run a performance test, the best case scenario is on the ASUS PCIe card with Samsung PM981 NVMe drives :

- 3.3GB/s READ speed (as advertised)
- 600MB/s WRITE speed (about 4 times less than what is advertised ; with a really significant crush in performance when cache get's filles at about 40GB).

I softraided the Samsung NVMe PM981 dirves on the ASUS PCIe card.
Speeds are now as follows :

- READ : 5.6GB/s (that is OK... even if not double of the single drive) ;
- WRITE : 1.2GB/s which exactly the double of the single drive performance.

It is like the kernel or MoBo sets the speed at AHCI speed (as it was a SATA drive).

Now if I use the above method, the results are quite different :

`dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=16384 conv=fdatasync,notrunc status=progress oflag=direct`

```bash
15183380480 octets (15 GB, 14 GiB) copiés, 5 s, 3,0 GB/s 
16384+0 enregistrements lus
16384+0 enregistrements écrits
17179869184 octets (17 GB, 16 GiB) copiés, 5,63686 s, 3,0 GB/s
```

`dd if=tempfile of=/dev/null bs=1M count=4096 status=progress iflag=direct`

```bash
4096+0 enregistrements lus
4096+0 enregistrements écrits
4294967296 octets (4,3 GB, 4,0 GiB) copiés, 1,00056 s, 4,3 GB/s
```

So it is totally inconsistent between both tools : GNOME-DISKS and dd...

In real world : if I move a really large (about 20GB) file from one NVMe to another one, I hardly get more than 850MB/s even on the softraided drives, which is really MUCH MUCH MUCH slower than expected...
Theory would be : 2 X 2400MB/s = 4800MB/s.
Reality : 6/7 times less.

You ask me : I think there is a real problem either in MoBo or in Linux.

I'll have to install Windows just to check if the problem is with the MoBo or with OS.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

**ISSUE VNMe slow write speed SOLVED**

Hi all,
I got 2 nvme drives. Samsusng 970 and SiliconPower p34a80. Dual boot on the Samsung. In windows10 both speeds are perfect. In ubuntu the SiliconPower write speed is 250MB/s when is NTFS, and 2GB/s when is ext4.
Spent 2 days of playing but finaly got solution in my case. Added in fstab the **big_writes** option.
My fstab line:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2AB1CB0844B0C2AD   /home/panayot/DATA-SSD   ntfs-3g nosuid,uid=1000,big_writes,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,async,x-gvfs-name=DATA-SSD 0 0
```

Good luck hope I helped :)

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP and my Samsung 970 is already EXT4. What is your kernel version?