# NVMe slow write speed capped at 513,2 MB/s

Tags: ssd, disk, nvme, io

Hello just bought a Samsung 980 Pro to be used with a fast camera.
I put it in a system with a X570-A-PRO mobo (On the M2_1 socket) and a Ryzen 9 5950x. I am running on the 22.4 with the 5.15.0-48 kernel version.

While benchmarking the Nvme with the disk utility I see that the writing speed is capped around 510 MBps as shown here :

[disk benchmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXnBk.png)

I also tried to copy video from another SSD on the M2_2 socket of the mobo, leading to copy speed as low as 200 Mbps and peaks at 600 MBps.

I already tried the solution proposed in [NVMe SSD slow write speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169815/nvme-ssd-slow-write-speed) however trying the same options do not solve problem.

if needed here is the output of `lscpi -vv` : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vn7zbGMqH6/

EDIT :
Seeing I am being downvoted, I would like to add that have been doing a lot for research and tried a lot solution in similar questions but none worked.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question doesn't belong here. It is either a hardware issue, or a kernel bug. There is no way to answer.

Comment: For some people it was configuration problem, and I am not the only one asking question regarding that matter so I am a bit a lost here.

Comment: The problem could come from how the disk utility works. I launched a benchmark using ` phoronix-test-suite benchmark 2104080-HA-2010158FI69` which should give better result and compare with other disks. Just done it with fio and it's giving promising results : https://openbenchmarking.org/result/2210117-NE-FIOSEQUEN24#table

Comment: Totally the same issue with Samsung 990 Pro and Ubuntu 22.04. When I copy from this drive to the same about 500MB/s when I copy from another to this one 900MB/s. On Windows - 2GB/s